# Ruby include module helper inside class - :cannot load such file

Tags: ruby

I've pure Ruby app with `HashHelper` located in `lib/hash_helpers.rb` which I want to use inside `Matcher` class in `lib/matcher.rb`.

To fire `Matcher` class I've got separate file in root directory of the app called `runner.rb`. How to include `HashHelpers` to be used inside the class `Matcher` ?

What I did is:

```
# runner.rb
require_relative 'lib/matcher'

matched_words = Matcher.new('dictionary.txt').call
p matched_words

# lib/matcher.rb
require_relative 'hash_helpers'

class Matcher
(...)
end

# lib/hash_helpers.rb
module HashHelpers
  extend self
(...)
end
```

When I tried to run `ruby runner.rb` I'm getting an error:

> lib/monads_matcher.rb:6:in `require_relative': cannot load such file -- /Users/usr/dictionary_app/lib/hash_helpers (LoadError)

Comment: Does `/Users/usr/dictionary_app/lib/hash_helpers.rb` exist? As a troubleshooting step, try a regular `require` with an absolute path.

Comment: @JaredBeck omg it was in `spec/lib` thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Sometimes, just sometimes, the error message is correct :P